# How to bind a command in WPF to a double click event handler of a control?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, command, double-click

I need to bind the double click event of a textblock (or potentially an image as well - either way, its a user control), to a command in my ViewModel.

TextBlock.InputBindings does not seem to bind correctly to my commands, any help?

Answer (score 299):

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="YourCommand" />
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

[http://thejoyofcode.com/Invoking_a_Command_on_a_Double_Click_or_other_Mouse_Gesture.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20111013172354/http://thejoyofcode.com/Invoking_a_Command_on_a_Double_Click_or_other_Mouse_Gesture.aspx)

Comment: +1 Personally, I think this answer should be the one marked as correct. Not only is it by far the simplest, but it can also be used with MVVM by binding to a `ICommand` in a view model: `<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />`

Comment: not working (maybe on some objects only) until you made this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/bind-double-click-to-a-viewmodel-command.aspx

Comment: Nice alternative to the messy attached behaviors :)

Comment: That's just a whole bag of awesome! It even applies to other controls out of the box. e.g. <TextBlock.InputBindings>

Comment: You can't, however, seem to use this in a Style.

Comment: Wow, 10 years into WPF programming I have always solved this, and seen this solved, by reverting to the mouse down events.

Comment: You can use it in a style but you have to use RelativeSource and find the actual DataContext. A style does not have a DataContext.

Answer (score 9):

it's simple let's use the MVVM way:
I'm using here MVVM Light which is easy to learn and strong.

1.put the following lines the xmlns declarations :

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"  
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
                                   assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
```

2.define your textblock just like this:

```
<textBlock text="Text with event">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                             Command="{Binding Edit_Command}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</textBlock>
```

3.then write your command code in your viewmodel !!!

ViewModel1.cs

```
Public RelayCommand Edit_Command
{
   get;
   private set;
}

Public ViewModel1()
{
   Edit_Command=new RelayCommand(()=>execute_me());
}

public void execute_me()
{
   //write your code here
}
```

I hope that works for you as I have used it in Real ERP application

Comment: A bit messy with these 'gala-soft-stuff' but the Interaction-approach is good!

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue where I needed to bind the MouseDoubleClick event of a listview to a command in my ViewModel.

The simplest solution I came up is putting a dummy button which has the desired command binding and calling the Execute method of the button's command in the eventhandler of the MouseDoubleClick event.

.xaml

```
 <Button Visibility="Collapsed" Name="doubleClickButton" Command="{Binding Path=CommandShowCompanyCards}"></Button>
                <ListView  MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCompany, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompanyList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
```

codebehind

```
     private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                doubleClickButton.Command.Execute(null);
            }
```

It is not straightforward but it is really simple and it works.