# Assigning a command to the EventSetter

Tags: .net, binding, eventsetter

How to assign a command to the Handler in EventSetter, I want to to write this:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="{Binding MyDoubleClickCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Marlon's Grech's [attached commands behaviours](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/), as mentioned in this [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293530/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf-to-a-double-click-event-handler-of-a-control)

Alternatively, as a simpler but less flexible solution, provide a `Handler` implementation in the code-behind to raise the command directly, like this:

```
<!-- In the XAML -->
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="MyPreviewDoubleClickHandler"/>

// In the code-behind
private void MyPreviewDoubleClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {
    object my_param = ...;
    MyCommand.Execute(my_param, this);
}
```