# Binding a command to listboxitems

Tags: wpf, xaml, command, viewmodel, relaycommand

Is it possible to bind a relaycommand to listboxitems when on of the items is clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a command in WPF to a double click event handler of a control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293530/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf-to-a-double-click-event-handler-of-a-control)

Answer (score 0):

You have the solution in irem's post there:
[How to bind a command in WPF to a double click event handler of a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293530/how-to-bind-a-command-in-wpf-to-a-double-click-event-handler-of-a-control)

:)

(PS: I'd advise you not to use AttachedBehaviors suggested. I think it's totally inappropriate to add such a complex architecture to your program for an action that basic, a single click)